# Understanding the `backgroundRefreshStatus` property

Tags: ios, background, core-location, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

I've an iOS app enabled for updating locations in Background Mode. I'm listening for the `UIApplicationBackgroundRefreshStatusDidChangeNotification` notification, and checking the `backgroundRefreshStatus` property. About the property, it is said in the documentation:

> This property reflects whether the app can be launched into the background to handle background behaviors, such as processing background location updates and performing background fetches.

I made some tests running the app in the simulator and, when I disable the "Background App Refresh" feature for the app in "Settings", I do receive the notification of the status change, but I see that locations keep being updated. I expected all background tasks to stop when "Background App Refresh" disabled by user... is that a simulator concern/bug? Or is the developer's responsibility to stop the background tasks anyway?

Thanks

Comment: are you still witnessing this behavior?